# CSS grid or flexbox for aligning image and text

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to make sure the image and the text in the columns are aligned to the bottom of the image and the top of the text. Does anybody know how to achieve this without explicitly setting the height of `.c-grid__content` to 200px?

Right now I'm using flexbox. Maybe css-grid is the answer?

Please take a look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/simoncoudeville/pen/VMZmVa?editors=1100#0.

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.c-grid {
  padding: 40px 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.c-grid__item {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.c-grid__picture {
  width: 100%;
}

.c-grid__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-grid">
  <article class="c-grid__item">
    <div class="c-grid__picture">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200">      
    </div>
    <div class="c-grid__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore ratione commodi corrupti itaque sed architecto!</p>
    </div>  
  </article>
  <article class="c-grid__item">
    <div class="c-grid__picture">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x600">       
    </div>
    <div class="c-grid__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore ratione commodi corrupti itaque sed architecto! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>  
  </article>
  <article class="c-grid__item">
    <div class="c-grid__picture">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400">       
    </div>
    <div class="c-grid__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore ratione commodi corrupti itaque sed architecto! </p>
    </div>  
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: The children of a flex container have no association with the children of another flex container. So getting these "cousins" to uniformly align isn't possible with pure CSS. You could alter your HTML to make these elements siblings, then they can relate to each other.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. But the images and text are related to each other. So separating them is not really an option.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the kind of thing you can easily achieve with GUI oriented languages like [QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-anchor-layout.html) but which is not suited for web page contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Align-items: baseline` on the flexbox container seems to do the trick in this case. See the solution here: https://codepen.io/simoncoudeville/pen/yzOvmN?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your codepen, this doesn't appear to require responsive design.  If I am correct in that assumption, why not use a table that separates the images and text by rows, vertically aligning the top row at the bottom and the bottom row at the top?

It would limit the important CSS to just a few lines:

```
.c-grid__picture {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.c-grid__content {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here is an example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/9h9u6s3v/)

Comment: Thanks, but this could also be done without tables. The thing is I don't want the images and text separated because they are part of the same article. While visually this looks like the answer, it really isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this setting the `flex-basis` of the `.c-grid__content` to 0.

```
.c-grid__content {
  ...
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/antibland/pen/WZrXpw?editors=1100

[image]

Comment: That's a neat trick. But `.c-grid__content` actually gets a height of 0. So if you would use that in a grid with multiple rows things would start overlapping. As you can see here: https://codepen.io/simoncoudeville/pen/yzOvmN?editors=1100.